# Unable to get any Docker Entrypoint from script working without continuous restarts

Tags: bash, docker, docker-entrypoint

I'm having trouble understanding or seeing some working version of using a bash script as an Entrypoint for a Docker container. I've been trying numerous things for about 5 hours now.

Even from this [official Docker blog](https://success.docker.com/article/use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data), using a bash-script as an entry-point still doesn't work.

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:stretch
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh / # backwards compat
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["postgres"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ "$1" = 'postgres' ]; then
    chown -R postgres "$PGDATA"

    if [ -z "$(ls -A "$PGDATA")" ]; then
        gosu postgres initdb
    fi

    exec gosu postgres "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

build.sh

```
docker build -t test .
```

run.sh

```
docker service create \
--name test \
test
```

Despite many efforts, I can't seem to get Dockerfile using an Entrypoint as a bash script that doesn't continuously restart and fail repeatedly.

My understanding is that `exec "$@"` was suppose to keep the container form immediately exiting, but I'm not sure if that's dependent some other process within the script failing.

I've tried using a `docker-entrypoint.sh` script that simply looked like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec "$@"
```

And since that also failed, I think that rules out something else going wrong inside the script being the cause of the failure.

What's also frustrating is there are no logs, either from `docker service logs test` or `docker logs [container_id]`, and I can't seem to find anything useful in `docker inspect [container_id]`.

I'm having trouble understanding everyone's confidence in `exec "$@"`. I don't want to resort to using something like `tail -f /dev/null` or using a command at `docker run`. I was hoping that there would be some consistent, reliable way that a `docker-entrypoint.sh` script could reliably used to start services that I could run with `docker run` as well for other things for services, but even on Docker's official blog and countless questions here and blogs from other sites, I can't seem get a single example to work.

I would really appreciate some insight into what I'm missing here.

Comment: Put aside swarm mode for a minute (it's a complication); if you just `docker run` the container you built locally, in the foreground, what does it say?

Answer (score 1):

$@ is just a string of the command line arguments. You are providing none, so it is executing a null string. That exits and will kill the docker. However, the exec command will always exit the running script - it destroys the current shell and starts a new one, it doesn't keep it running.

What I think you want to do is keep calling this script in kind of a recursive way. To actually have the script call itself, the line would be:

```
exec $0
```

$0 is the name of the bash file (or function name, if in a function). In this case it would be the name of your script.

Also, I am curious your desire not to use tail -f /dev/null? Creating a new shell over and over as fast as the script can go is not more performant. I am guessing you want this script to run over and over to just check your if condition.

In that case, a while(1) loop would probably work.

Comment: The `CMD` from the `Dockerfile` is passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`.  As noted in the question, ending an entrypoint script with `exec "$@"` is an extremely common pattern to run "whatever the command is" as the main container process after doing some initialization.

Comment: But it will still kill his entrypoint script and terminate the docker as he has it set up. Tail -f /dev/null is a perfectly valid way to do what he wants to do.

Answer (score 1):

What you show, in principle, should work, and is one of the standard Docker patterns.

[The interaction between `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) is pretty straightforward.  If you provide both, then the main container process is whatever `ENTRYPOINT` (or `docker run --entrypoint`) specifies, and it is passed `CMD` (or the command at the end of `docker run`) as arguments.  In this context, ending an entrypoint script with `exec "$@"` just means "replace me with the `CMD` as the main container process".

So, the pattern here is

1. Do some initial setup, like `chown`ing a possibly-external data directory; then
2. `exec "$@"` to run whatever was passed as the command.

---

In your example there are a couple of things worth checking; it won't run as shown.

Whatever you provide as the `ENTRYPOINT` needs to obey the usual rules for executable commands: if it's a bare command, it must be in `$PATH`; it must have the executable bit set in its file permissions; if it's a script, its interpreter must also exist; if it's a binary, it must be statically linked or all of its shared library dependencies must be in the image already.  For your script you might need to make it executable if it isn't already

```
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

The other thing with this setup is that (definitionally) if the `ENTRYPOINT` exits, the whole container exits, and the Bourne shell `set -e` directive tells the script to exit on any error.  In the artifacts in the question, [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) isn't a standard part of the `debian` base image, so your entrypoint will fail (and your container will exit) trying to run that command.  (That won't affect the very simple case though.)

Finally, if you run into trouble running a container under an orchestration system like Docker Swarm or Kubernetes, one of your first steps should be to run the same container, locally, in the foreground: use `docker run` without the `-d` option and see what it prints out.  For example:

```
% docker build .
% docker run --rm c5fb7da1c7c1
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"docker-entrypoint.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled 
% chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
% docker build .
% docker run --rm f5a239f2758d
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 3: exec: postgres: not found
```

(Using the `Dockerfile` and short `docker-entrypoint.sh` from the question, and using the final image ID from `docker build .` in those `docker run` commands.)